# Solving for a matrix in sympy

Tags: math, matrix, sympy, matrix-multiplication, symbolic-math

I want to solve for Ka = F. i do this by defining a new matrix M = Ka-F. And solves for this when its zero. This also works very well for a 2x2 matrix i only have 2 unkown so it should be very trivial to do this one but sympy wont solve it for some reason i cant really seem to find out what the problem is... this is the code:

```
from sympy import *
K = Matrix([[1/2,0,0,-1/2],[0,1,0,-1],[0,0,1/2,-1/2],[-1/2,-1,-1/2,2]])
T1,T4 = symbols("T_1,T_4")
T = Matrix([[T1],[20],[20],[T4]])
F = Matrix([[29.1666],[16.666],[12.5],[41.6666]])
M = K*T-F
solve(M)
```

Comment: A way i can solve it is by doing this :
    M2 = Matrix([[M[0]],[M[3]]]) NEW LINE: solve(M2). But is there a way i can do this directly?

Comment: Your equations are inconsistent. There are no solutions.

Comment: @Lopehert The comments aren't meant to add code. Instead, you are invited to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72078058/edit) your post and add extra code and clarifications.  Also note that sympy tries to find exact solutions. Floats, which are imprecise by definition, often lead to bizarre outcomes.  Whenever feasible, try to use exact numbers, such as `S(1)/2` or `S(175)/6` (or `Rational(1,2)`).  See also [sympy's gotchas](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#two-final-notes-and).